# Alternative methods for deprecated gym.wrappers.Monitor()

Tags: openai-gym

The example is from Chapter 8 of Grokking Deep Reinforcement Learning written by Miguel Morales.

[Please click here](https://github.com/mimoralea/gdrl/blob/master/notebooks/chapter_08/chapter-08.ipynb)

The `wrappers.Monitor` is deprecated after the book is published. The code in question is as below:

```
env = wrappers.Monitor(
        env, mdir, force=True, 
        mode=monitor_mode, 
        video_callable=lambda e_idx: record) if monitor_mode else env
```

I searched the internet and tried 2 methods but failed.

**1- gnwrapper.Monitor**

I `pip install gym-notebook-wrapper` and `import gnwrapper`, then rewrite the code

```
env = gnwrapper.Monitor(gym.make(env_name),directory="./")
```

A  `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` error message is returned.

**2- gym.wrappers.RecordVideo**

I `from gym.wrappers import RecordVideo` then rewrite the code

```
env = RecordVideo(gym.make(env_name), "./")
```

A `AttributeError: 'CartPoleEnv' object has no attribute 'videos'` error message is returned.

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @Maron does the proposed solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, the best way to work around the problem is to downgrade the gym version to 0.20.0, in order to preserve the `wrappers.Monitor` function.

Moreover, the `subprocess.Popen` and `subprocess.check_output` does not work as the original author suggested, so I use `moviepy` (please `pip install moviepy` if you do not have this libarary and `from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip` at the very beginning) to change MP4 to GIF files. The code in `get_gif_html` is amended as follows.

```
gif_path = basename + '.gif'
    if not os.path.exists(gif_path):
        videoClip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
        videoClip.write_gif(gif_path, logger=None)

    gif = io.open(gif_path, 'r+b').read()
```

The program now completely works.

Edit (24 Jul 2022):
The following solution is for gym version **0.25.0**, as I hope the program works for later versions. Windows 10 and Juptyer Notebook is used for the demonstration.

(1) Maintain the `moviepy` improvement stated above

(2) import  `from gym.wrappers.record_video import RecordVideo` and substitute

```
env = wrappers.Monitor(
            env, mdir, force=True, 
            mode=monitor_mode, 
            video_callable=lambda e_idx: record) if monitor_mode else
```

with this

```
if monitor_mode:
    env = RecordVideo(env, mdir, episode_trigger=lambda e_idx:record)
    env.reset()
    env.start_video_recorder()
else:
    env = env
```

`RecordVideo` function takes `(env, video_folder, episode_trigger)` arguments, and `video_callable` and `episode_trigger` are the same thing.

(3) Loss of `env.videos` in `get_gif_html` function in new versions.

In the old setting, after the video is recorded, the MP4 and meta.json files are stored in the following address with a random file name

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za3Sd.jpg

This `env.videos` function returns a list of tuples, each tuples consisted of address path of MP4 and meta.json.

I tried to recreate the `env.videos` by
(a) declare the mdir as global variable

```
def get_make_env_fn(**kargs):
    def make_env_fn(env_name, seed=None, render=None, record=False,
                    unwrapped=False, monitor_mode=None, 
                    inner_wrappers=None, outer_wrappers=None):
        global mdir
        mdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
```

(b) in the `demo_progression` and `demo_last` function, grouping all MP4 and meta_json files, zipping them and use list comprehension to make a new `env_videos` variable (as opposed to `env.videos`)

```
        env.close()
        
        mp4_files = ([(mdir + '\\' + file) for file in os.listdir(mdir) if file.endswith('.mp4')])
        meta_json_files = ([(mdir + '\\' + file) for file in os.listdir(mdir) if file.endswith('.meta.json')])
        env_videos = [(mp4, meta_json) for mp4, meta_json in zip(mp4_files, meta_json_files)]
                
        data = get_gif_html(env_videos=env_videos,
```

These are all the changes.